# Sublime Text 3 - Proper javascript intellisense?

Tags: javascript, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I'm trying to find a plugin that will give me proper intellisense for JavaScript.

My background for comparison and expectations are based on Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper.

I have currently installed the following plugins:

- Alignment
- DocBlockr
- Emmet
- FileBrowser
- SublimeCodeIntel
- SublimeLinter (with SublimeLinter-jshint and SublimeLinter-json)

Despite the fact that SublimeLinter should show errors in JS, it does **not**. The only "intellisense" is this:

[image]

Hurray - the intellisense tells me that it's a function! What about the function signature? Arguments / Parameters?

When I begin to type the arguments, it doesn't tell me that the function takes any parameters?

Typing `testFunction(` should - in my point of view - trigger a small popup telling me that the first parameter is called `arg1` and the expected type is `Number`. But it doesn't?

I would like to know if there's any other plugins I can use, or if the ones installed conflict with one another?

Thanks in advance.